# scrapy crawl multiple pages, extracting data and saving into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

Hi can someone help me out I seem to be stuck, I am learning how to crawl and save into mysql us scrapy. I am trying to get scrapy to crawl all of the website pages. Starting with "start_urls", but it does not seem to automatically crawl all of the pages only the one, it does save into mysql with pipelines.py. It does also crawl all pages when provided with urls in a f = open("urls.txt") as well as saves data using pipelines.py.

here is my code

### test.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from gotp.items import GotPItem
from scrapy.log import *
from gotp.settings import *
from gotp.items import *

class GotP(CrawlSpider):
    name = "gotp"
    allowed_domains = ["www.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sss"]
    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=('')),
            callback ="parse",
            follow=True
        )
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        prices = hxs.select("//div[@class="sliderforward arrow"]")
        for price in prices:
            item = GotPItem()
            item ["price"] = price.select("text()").extract()
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to follow the pagination and extract the results.

In this case, you can avoid using `CrawlSpider` and use regular `Spider` class.

The idea would be to parse the first page, extract total results count, calculate how much pages to go and yield `scrapy.Request` instances to the same URL providing `s` GET parameter value.

Implementation example:

```
import scrapy

class GotP(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gotp"
    allowed_domains = ["www.sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sss"]

    results_per_page = 100

    def parse(self, response):
        total_count = int(response.xpath('//span[@class="totalcount"]/text()').extract()[0])
        for page in xrange(0, total_count, self.results_per_page):
            yield scrapy.Request("http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sss?s=%s&" % page, callback=self.parse_result, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        results = response.xpath("//p[@data-pid]")
        for result in results:
            try:
                print result.xpath(".//span[@class='price']/text()").extract()[0]
            except IndexError:
                print "Unknown price"
```

This would follow the pagination and print prices on the console. Hope this is a good starting point.

Comment: I am trying to crawl all of the pages on craigslist.org starting with the "start_urls". not necessary to be next page or something similar but any page which has the same "class='price'". the problem is not just going to page 2,3,4,5, etc. but it is that I want the full website to be crawled, no matter what the page url.

Comment: If I ad url sitemap.txt, it will crawl full list or urls, but just giving a starting point. it will not.

Comment: O.M.G! I was using def parse(self, response): in the Rule for crawlSprider. rule 1. do not use parse. I fixed it by using def parse_page(self, response):. works fin now